# Register form PHP SQL

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to make a registration form. This form needs to add data to the database when the submit is clicked. it's not giving any errors or messages. this is my code, I hope someone can help me.

```
<body>
 <form action="" method"post" class="form">
    <div class="form-group1">
    <label for="" >Username :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="tb-username" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group2">
    <label for="" >Password :</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="tb-password" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-submit" name="register">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['register']))
    {
    if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']))
    {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", " ", "vbproject");

        if(mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_errno());
            exit();
        }

        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password)
                VALUES('$username', '$password')";

        mysqli_close($link);
    }
    }
     ?>

</body>
```

Comment: You do not prepare or execute your SQL.

Comment: Storing plain passwords, mmmmm

Comment: you are supposed to call the query in order to save the data into the database

Comment: @MahiParmar im a beginner in php. what is the best way to call the query?

Comment: i have already answered please check @acesteef

Comment: @acesteef Just for security's sake. [Preparing SQL Statements 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263371/how-can-prepared-statements-protect-from-sql-injection-attacks) [Preparing SQL Statements 2](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)  [Hashing and verifying passwords](https://codeaddiction.net/articles/4/hash-and-verify-passwords-in-php---the-right-way)

Comment: mysqli_query($con, $sql); // this Line Missing after Your SQL Query

Comment: None of the answers (so far) address the point @u_mulder makes of storing plain passwords, which is so important these days for security.

Comment: @NigelRen I gave him some links in the comments.I don't think giving an answer just about the security issue's would be appropiate, since then you would go off topic..

Comment: @Rick_Jellema you don't need to give an answer which just addresses one point, but an answer should show the best way to solve a problem.

Comment: @NigelRen Gotta give a `true` to your comment.

Answer (score 2):

You have an error here

```
<form action="" method"post" class="form">
```

replace this with

```
<form action="" method="post" class="form">
```

you missed the `=` sign causing your request as `GET` request and you are accessing  as `POST` method

Answer (score 0):

Add this line before closing connection, it will execute your query which is what you are not doing

```
mysqli_query($link,$sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

you Need too:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password)
        VALUES('$username', '$password')";
 $result = $link->query($sql);
 if($result === true){
  echo "Insert Success";
 }else{
  echo "Insert failed";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change `method"post"` to `method="post"` in form tag.

```
 <body>

    <form action="" method="post" class="form">
    <div class="form-group1">
    <label for="" >Username :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="tb-username" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group2">
    <label for="" >Password :</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="tb-password" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-submit" name="register">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['register']))
    {
    if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']))
    {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", " ", "vbproject");

        if(mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_errno());
            exit();
        }

        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password)
                VALUES('$username', '$password')";
        if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
         echo 'Inserted';
        }else{
          echo 'Not Inserted';
        }
        mysqli_close($link);
    }
    }
     ?>

    </body>
```

Add these line in your code :

```
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
         echo 'Inserted';
        }else{
          echo 'Not Inserted';
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not run the mysql query. Please Find Below solution:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password)
            VALUES('$username', '$password')";

mysqli_query($con, $sql); // this Line Missing

mysqli_close($link);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an observation your code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['register']))
{
```

But $_POST['register'} has not been assigned any value and the if statement will fail 
suggest you add value="submit" here

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-submit" name="register">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how the flow will go

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", " ", "vbproject");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// Perform queries 
 $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password)
            VALUES('$username', '$password')";
mysqli_query($con, $sql);

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```